# Springboot annotations in plain/vanilla java

Tags: java

Can I use springboot annotations like @Bean, @Component, @Autowired etc in plain java project with just using gradle dependencies?

Comment: "with just using gradle dependencies" what do you mean?

Comment: You can, provided you include related dependencies like Spring core, spring context to name the few

Answer (score 0):

To use spring frameworks annotations the project should be either spring boot or a project with all the required spring dependencies to support the above mentioned annotations.

Answer (score 0):

No. Spring uses those annotations for the inversion of control. Without this framework they are useless in plain java.